# Listing files which will be installed by .deb

Tags: package-management, deb

How can i list all the files (and their future locations) which will be installed by invoking 'dpkg -i' on a .deb file? Which makefile target of the source package determines those (is it the default 'install' target?)

(The second part of the question concerns the package creation process. I want the list of files installed by 'make install' and the list of files installed by the .deb package to be the same)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list the contents of a deb file by running

```
dpkg-deb --contents package.deb
```

`dpkg-deb` can show a whole lot of information about a deb package. You can see the other options by running `dpkg-deb --help`.

Unfortunately, you can't determine what files a Makefile will install. However, you can install to a temporary directory by setting the `DESTDIR` variable. Note that this works well mainly on Makefiles generated by `autotools` ie. the `./configure` script. For example:

```
cd sourcecode-1.2
./configure --prefix=/usr           #Just the usual compiling stuff
make
mkdir /tmp/installedfiles           #Create a temporary directory for the files
make DESTDIR=/tmp/installedfiles install
```

That last `make` line will install the files in `/tmp/installedfiles`. You can then see the files that would be created, although those files and directories will all be relative to the prefix specified in the configure script. In other words, `/tmp/installedfiles/bin/mainprogram` would be installed as `/usr/bin/mainprogram`.

I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: Okay but what determines the files which will be installed? I noticed a difference between the list of files installed using 'make install' and files which are installed by dpkg -i on the package built with the source

Comment: If you install the deb, only the files and folders shown in `dpkg-deb --contents` will be installed. If you run `make install`, only the files listed in `/tmp/installedfiles` will be installed. How was the list different between the two? Could you edit your question and add that? Also, could you post the package you are referring to?

Comment: I am trying create a package with a custom build (custom ./configure options) of gnash. See updated question.

Comment: When you create your DEB file, try setting the configure options in the `debian/rules` file like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/638925/

Comment: Also, if all you want is to edit the configure options, just download the source from the Ubuntu repo with `apt-get source gnash` and change your configure options in `debian/rules` starting from line 34.

Answer (score 0):

A deb file is an archive file which you can extract to see its contents.

From Wikipedia

> Since Debian 0.93, a deb file is
>   implemented as an ar archive.
>   Canonical contents of this archive are
>   three files:
>
> - debian-binary: deb format version    number. This is "2.0" for current
>     versions of Debian.
> - control.tar.gz: all package    meta-information.
> - data.tar, data.tar.gz, data.tar.bz2,     data.tar.lzma or
>     data.tar.xz: the       actual
>     installable files.
>
> The debian-binary file must be the
>   first entry in the archive, otherwise
>   it will not be recognized as a Debian
>   package.

So when you extract a deb file you will get a data file i.e data.tar/data.tar.gz/data.tar.lzma/data.tar.xz. Extract this file and you will get all the files/directories that this deb will create or put files into.